# jQuery plugin - not quite autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin (or some other library that'll work with jquery) that will do autocomplete-type behavior. A couple features I'm looking for

1. support text/id paired data, where the text is displayed in the "dropdown" and textbox, but an ID is available to be submitted with the form.
2. ID's are not required to be submitted to the server - that is, items not in the list could be entered into the textbox
3. prefereably the ability to style the markup of items in the list

This http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin/ is a pretty good match, but seems to have a couple bugs. The jQuery UI implementation seems to be missing at least the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but it's what I use, Lightweight and easy to style too!

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: I am by no means a js/jquery expert but I managed to allow entry not in the list, there's a part of the JS file about "No results found" or something, look around there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you mean because of my poor english. But I found some jQuery Plugins for you, which might be useful:

1. http://jquery-plugins.net/#
2. http://www.jqueryplugins.com/